# Как центровать обьекты на странице вне зависимости от разрешения экрана?

Tags: html, css

Я часто вижу на сайтах, как у них контент в центре в блоке, а блок всегда (при разном масштабе и разрешениии экрана) в центре страницы. Я уже пробовал `<center></ceter>` и `<div align="center"></div>` и `#ид дива{margin/padding:50%;}` но всё равно, если внутри дива сделать `position:absolute;`, то всё не в центре, а как прописано в `left/right:` и `top/bottom:`

Помогите, как сделать блок, всегда находящийся в середине страницы/другого блока, желательно без Css3. И ещё один вопрос, :) чтобы сделать по ширине до конца странице надо width: 100%, а как по высоте от текущей позиции сделать до конца страницы?

Comment: если блоку прописать position:absolute, то такой блок уедет в верхний угол экрана, чтобы он был вместе с вашим враппером, нужно этому врапперу задать position:relative и тогда абсолютно позиционированный блок будет внутри враппера, может у вас из-за этого проблема с центровкой? Как уже вам говорили margin:0 auto и фиксированная ширина 100% рабочий пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

горизонтальное центрирование блока фиксированной ширины

```
div{
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[горизонтальное центрирование блока плавающей ширины](http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/technogrette/html/align-center/)

чтобы задать высоту блока равную 100% высоты видимой части страницы её же (`width:100%`) нужно задать ещё и тегу `html` и тегу `body`

Comment: Не получается!

Comment: значит есть стили которые влияют на целевой блок - ищите их. это рабочий код который я использовал неоднократно.

Answer (score 1):

```
postion: absolute
```

не влияет на центрирование элемента. с помощью этого свойства можно абсолютно расположить его относительно родительского элемента. то есть Вы жёстко указываете, где должен располагаться элемент. поэтому при разном разрешении - и сам элемент будет перемещаться.
предыдущий совет - самый действенный способ. я им тоже всегда пользуюсь. есть ещё способ: указать отрицательную величину левого поля, равную половине ширины родительского элемента. в сочетании эти два способа дают практически точное центрирование элемента на странице.