# Вёрстка страницы с фиксированым меню

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Нужно сверстать страницу с фиксированым по бокам от контента меню. Ширина контента фиксированая, он должен быть расположен по центру.

При вёрстке таблицами не получается нормально сделать прокрутку. При верстке div'ами - не получается нормально центровать.

Как лучше сделать?

---

Лучший вариант, который у меня получался - две таблицы (позиционирование: абсолютное + фиксированое), только здесь проблема в том, что ссылки меню не кликабельны, т.к. они перекрываются прозрачной ячейкой другой таблицы. [Вот сама страница](http://crash-test.at.ua/temp/_2tables.htm) *(сюда нормально скопировать не смог)*

Comment: Что делали? что получилось? Примры - результаты!!!

Comment: воспользуйтесь поиском на сайте!много интересного и полезного найдёте!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для блока меню в css указываем:

```
position: fixed;
```

Центрирование основного блока:

```
margin: 0px /* или другое значение */ auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Crasher, а если присмотреться? [вопрос №1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/71094/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83), [вопрос №2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/44579/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=44649#44649), [вопрос №3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/33684/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=33707#33707), [вопрос №4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/33645/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=33705#33705). Надеюсь, поможет.

Comment: Спасибо, в следующий раз буду внимательнее искать :)